# can't delete bugged file on ext3

Tags: linux, file-management, ext3

I have a file called "Last Tabs" on my ext3 filesystem that I can't delete (created by chromium). It appears to be bugged. If I use `ls -l` I get

```
ls: cannot access Last Tabs: No such file or directory
total 0
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? Last Tabs
```

I can't even list the inode `ls -i`

```
ls: cannot access Last Tabs: No such file or directory
? Last Tabs
```

And I can create a second file with the same name `touch "Last Tabs"` and then `ls -li` returns

```
total 0
3411997 -rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Sep 22 14:25 Last Tabs
3411997 -rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Sep 22 14:25 Last Tabs
```

But if I then delete "Last Tabs" I only delete the one I just created.

Any ideas what's going on here? I really want to delete the parent directory but I can't without deleting that file.

Comment: So I assume you can't recursively delete the parent directory? What about running `stat *` to get the inode?

Comment: @miyalys I use `rm` and it complains that it can't delete `Last Tabs` and then it can't delete the parent because it's not empty. `stat *` returns `stat: cannot stat ‘Last Tabs’: No such file or directory`

Comment: Hm, okay. Maybe try running `fsck` on the file system? It's a bit of a guess, though, to be honest.

Comment: You could try looking at it from a bootable LiveCD: this bypasses any locks in the live OS. You can run `fsck` from there, too, as @miyalys suggests .

Comment: Try `mkdir test0000; mv Last* test0000; cd test0000; find L* -execute rm -f {} \;` ; else you can  try `mkdir test0000; mv Last* test0000; rm -rf test0000`. Note have to be the only file that can match the regex `Last*`... if not move the other ones in a safe place and try again. When you can run `fsck`.

Comment: I performed `fsck` from a liveCD and the issue still persists. @Hastur This fails at `mv` with `mv: cannot stat ‘Last Tabs’: No such file or directory` I think i will just create a new partition and move everything except that file there and conclude that ext3 is garbage.

Comment: Drastic :) There are a lot of attempt you can try before. You should try `rm -fi *` in that directory. __Warning__ it can delete the other files but you will answer no :).   Did you try to do `rm Last` and then press the Tab to autocomplete? You can else move all the other files from that directory in another then to delete the directory with only this file inside. E.g. they are in the directory `A/B` you move all the other files in `A/C` then you go in `A` and from there you delete `B` with `rm -rf B`. Finally you give a `mv C B`.  Else you can do `find L* -execute rm -fi {} \;`